# Displaying category thumbnail for child categories of a parent on homepage

Tags: category, collection

I'm currently loading the child categories of a parent category by ID on the homepage:-

```
$preparednessCategoryId = 3;
$pcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($preparednessCategoryId);
$psubcats = $pcat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$psubcats) as $psubCatid):
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($psubCatid);

    if($_category->getIsActive()):

        //markup here

    endif;
```

But I can't for the life of me display the category thumbnail and despite reading 400 odd other posts about the same difficulty, nothing I have tried has worked.

From what I can gather, it needs to be passed into the collection(?) but the following doesn't work for me:-

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($psubCatid)->getThumbnail();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem if you are trying to display category thumbnails on a grid.

Ultimately I found this module the most useful:

- https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-resize-category-images

Also, refrain from doing while/foreach loops with a `Mage::getModel()->load()` as it does not scale well.

- http://vinaikopp.com/2014/06/09/preloading-for-scalabiliy/
- http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf

Comment: Thanks @B00MER, I shall check out that extension and see if we can work around the problem by using parts of it. Good call on pre-fetching outside of the `foreach` loop, once we know we can actually get the category thumbnail, we'll improve the code.

Comment: As a workaround (solution?), I am now loading `getImageURL()` but resizing the images to use instead as the category thumbnails. It does the job so that will do for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar functionality, albeit on the parent category pages to list its child (sub) categories.

Count the number of subcategories:

```
<div id="category-landing">
    <?php $_numCats = count($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories()); ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
```

Foreach subcategory, grab the name:

```
    <?php $_catName = Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name'); ?>
        <div class="category-landing-row col-md-12 col4-set">
```

Create the content, with thumbnails:

```
            <div class="sub-category col-<?php echo $col.' '.$i; if($i%4==0): echo " last"; endif; ?>">
            <?php if ($_thumbnail = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcat->getId())->getThumbnail()): ?>
                <?php $_imageurl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $_thumbnail;?>
                <div class="sub-category-image">
                    <a title="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><img width="155" height="155" alt="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" src="<?php echo $_imageurl ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="sub-categories">
                <a title="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo  $_catName ?></a>
                <?php if (count($_subcat->getChildrenCategories())>0): ?>  
                    <ul class="sub-sub-categories">
                    <?php foreach ($_subcat->getChildrenCategories() as $_subsubcat):?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $_subsubcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subsubcat, $_subsubcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Close it all out:

```
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

I've taken out a counter to limit the number of subcat's displayed, but the functionality is there.

The complete code:

```
<div id="category-landing">
    <?php $_numCats = count($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories()); ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
    <?php $_catName = Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name'); ?>
        <div class="category-landing-row col-md-12 col4-set">
            <div class="sub-category col-<?php echo $col.' '.$i; if($i%4==0): echo " last"; endif; ?>">
            <?php if ($_thumbnail = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcat->getId())->getThumbnail()): ?>
                <?php $_imageurl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $_thumbnail;?>
                <div class="sub-category-image">
                    <a title="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><img width="155" height="155" alt="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" src="<?php echo $_imageurl ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="sub-categories">
                <a title="<?php echo  $_catName ?>" href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo  $_catName ?></a>
                <?php if (count($_subcat->getChildrenCategories())>0): ?>  
                    <ul class="sub-sub-categories">
                    <?php foreach ($_subcat->getChildrenCategories() as $_subsubcat):?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $_subsubcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subsubcat, $_subsubcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you actually using Magento 1.9.X where you have this working? `getThumbnail` doesn't exist in the category model, I had to manually add the function (even then, it still doesn't load it). Plus you have to [run the SQL queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27938968/898933) to create the attribute. None of this you mentioned which makes me think that the version of Magento you are running is < 1.9 when the category thumbnail exists?

Comment: @zigojacko You are correct, I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0